# VS2022: std::string.c_str() Dangling pointer warning

Tags: c++, stdstring

I am getting a dangling pointer warning from VS2022 for this code snippet:

```
chars = (unsigned char*)(pProgram->getProgramUUID().c_str());
memcpy(&outputBuffer[bufferPosition], chars, numChars);
```

Warning

```
Warning C26815  The pointer [chars] is dangling because it points at a temporary instance which was destroyed.
```

`getProgramUUID()` returns a `std::string` and is defined as

```
std::string getProgramUUID() { return m_programUUID; }
```

basically this is just a `memcpy` from a pointer returned by `c_str()`.

Any idea if this is a genuine issue, or this is just VS being pedantic?

Regards,
Abhishek

Comment: why not try `std::string  programUUID = pProgram->getProgramUUID()` and then `auto chars = programUUID.c_str();`

Comment: It would also work if getProgramUUID returned a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `getProgramUUID()` returns a string by value, that string object will be destructed and cease to exist once the full expression (the assignment) is finished. The pointer to the contained string will become immediately invalid.

As a workaround you could call `getProgramUUID()` as part of the `memcpy` call:

```
memcpy(&outputBuffer[bufferPosition], pProgram->getProgramUUID().c_str(), numChars);
```